# Ruby on rails - Reference the same model twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, relationship

Is it possible to set up a double relationship in `activerecord` models via the `generate scaffold` command?

For example, if I had a `User` model and a `PrivateMessage` model, the private_messages table would need to keep track of both the `sender` and `recipient`.

Obviously, for a single relationship I would just do this:

```
ruby script/generate scaffold pm title:string content:string user:references
```

Is there a similar way to set up two relations?

Also, is there anyway to set up aliases for the relations?

So rather than saying:

```
@message.user
```

You can use something like:

`@message.sender` or `@message.recipient`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Add this to your Model

```
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User"
```

And you are able to call `@message.sender` and `@message.recipient` and both reference to the User model.

Instead of `user:references` in your generate command, you'd need `sender:references` and `recipient:references`

Answer (score 141):

Here's a complete answer to this issue, in case people visiting this question are new to Ruby on Rails and having a hard time putting everything together (as I was when I first looked into this).

Some parts of the solution take place in your Migrations and some in your Models:

### Migrations

```
class CreatePrivateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :private_messages do |t|
      t.references :sender
      t.references :recipient
    end
    # Rails 5+ only: add foreign keys
    add_foreign_key :private_messages, :users, column: :sender_id, primary_key: :id
    add_foreign_key :private_messages, :users, column: :recipient_id, primary_key: :id
  end
end
```

Here you are specifying that there are two columns in this table that will be referred to as :sender and :recipient and which hold references to another table. Rails will actually create columns called 'sender_id' and 'recipient_id' for you. In our case they will each reference rows in the Users table, but we specify that in the models, not in the migrations.

### Models

```
class PrivateMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Here you are creating a property on the PrivateMessage model named :sender, then specifying that this property is related to the User class. Rails, seeing the "belongs_to :sender", will look for a column in your database called "sender_id", which we defined above, and use that to store the foreign key. Then you're doing the exact same thing for the recipient.

This will allow you to access your Sender and Recipient, both instances of the User model, through an instance of the PrivateMessage model, like this:

```
@private_message.sender.name
@private_message.recipient.email
```

Here is your User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_private_messages, :class_name => 'PrivateMessage', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_private_messages, :class_name => 'PrivateMessage', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
end
```

Here you are creating a property on the User Model named :sent_private_messages, specifying that this property is related to the PrivateMessage Model, and that the foreign key on the PrivateMessage model which relates it to this property is called 'sender_id'. Then you are doing the same thing for received private messages.

This allows you to get all of a users sent or received private messages by doing something like this:

```
@user.sent_private_messages
@user.received_private_messages
```

Doing either of these will return an array of instances of the PrivateMessage model.

....

Comment: The `class_name` keys for the `PrivateMessage` model should be symbols I can't edit this myself because edits must be at least 6 characters.

Comment: @TimFletcher The examples on this page all use strings, not symbols: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to. Maybe the `to_s` message is sent to a passed Symbol (just guessing here)?

Comment: excellent, very comprehensive answer. Rails 5 has an update which I think could help improve your answer -- ensuring that foreign key constraints get added to the database. I've included an edit to the migration in an answer below if you'd like to update your answer with it.

Comment: as an additional note, I ran into "relation does not exist" errors when trying this - both tables must already exist before adding foreign keys. I had to create the add_foreign_keys in a separate migration after creating both tables in my case

Comment: In Rails 5 and above you can put the `foreign_key` statements into the `create_table` block like this: `t.references :sender, foreign_key: { to_table: 'users' }`

Answer (score 18):

hi there 
to have both side relation do as bellow in your both models:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to     :sender,
                :class_name => "User",
                :foreign_key  => "sender_id"

 belongs_to     :recipient,
                :class_name => "User",
                :foreign_key  => "recipient_id" 
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many      :sent, 
                :class_name => "Message",
                :foreign_key  => "sent_id"

  has_many      :received, 
                :class_name => "Message", 
                :foreign_key  => "received_id"
end
```

I hope this help you...

Answer (score 11):

The above answers, while excellent, do not create foreign key constraints in the database, instead only creating indexes and bigint columns. To ensure that the foreign key constraint is enforced, add the following to your migration:

```
class CreatePrivateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def change
        create_table :private_messages do |t|
          t.references :sender
          t.references :recipient
        end

        add_foreign_key :private_messages, :users, column: :sender_id, primary_key: :id
        add_foreign_key :private_messages, :users, column: :recipient_id, primary_key: :id
    end
end
```

This will ensure that the indices get created on the `sender_id` and `recipient_id` as well as the foreign key constraints in the database you're using.

Comment: this is a proper solution for rails 5