# Rails has_many custom ActiveRecord Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have a Teams model and a Fixtures model. The Fixtures model has an away team and a home team.I followed the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260455/256917) and have most things working.

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home, class_name: 'Team'
  belongs_to :away, class_name: 'Team'
end


class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games, :class_name => 'Fixture', :foreign_key => 'home_id'
  has_many :away_games, :class_name => 'Fixture', :foreign_key => 'away_id'
end
```

I want to be able to call @team.fixtures to get a list of all of the teams fixtures, currently @team.home_games gives me the home fixtures and @team.away_games gives me the aways.
How can I write a `has_many :games` similar to `has_many :home_games`, and is that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the best way would be to write **an instance method** for that:

In the Team model:

```
def games
  Fixture.where("home_id = ? OR away_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
end
```

Use it like a regular method:

```
Team.first.games
#=> [<Fixture id: ... >, <Fixture id: ... >, ... ]
```

This should **return an ActiveRecord::Relation** which **is re-usable for scope-chaining**, etc.

(Here is a similar question, but with `has_one`: [Rails Model has_many with multiple foreign_keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307581/rails-model-has-many-with-multiple-foreign-keys))

---

Also, you could make a class method from it using the id of the Team (if you already have the team_id but not the Team instance object):

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games, :class_name => 'Fixture', :foreign_key => 'home_id'
  has_many :away_games, :class_name => 'Fixture', :foreign_key => 'away_id'

  def games
    Team.games(self.id)
  end

  def self.games(team_id)
    Fixture.where('fixtures.home_id = ? OR fixtures.away_id = ?', team_id, team_id)    
  end
end
```

And use it like this:

```
Team.games(params[:team_id])
# or
@team = Team.where(id: params[:id]).first
@team.games
```

Comment: I believe that if you do this, you have to be careful because you cannot use include, and you could expose yourself to N+1 queries.