# Self Join on a Table using Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model named `Transaction`. 
Each transaction has four fields:

- TransactionID
- Type of Transaction
- UserID
- Parent TransactionID

There are further two types of `Transaction`:

- Debit Transaction
- Payback Transaction

For every Payback Transaction, the TransactionID of the Debit Transaction is mentioned in Parent TransactionID field.

Using ActiveRecord Query I have to find the unpaid Debit Transactions of a particular user ID.

---

Example data:

```
TransactionID Type of Transaction UserID Parent TransactionID
123           Debit               1      null
124           Debit               1      null
125           Credit              1      123
127           Debit               1      null
```

Querying the above data should return Transactions: `124, 127`.

Comment: Is it correct that `DebitTransaction` has many `PaybackTransaction`s?

Comment: There is only one `PaybackTransaction` for one `DebitTransaction`.

Comment: Try this `Transaction.where(parent_transaction_id: nil, type: 'Debit').where.not(id: Transaction.select(:parent_transaction_id).uniq)`

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay your solution works but is it feasible to do without subquery and using self-join table statement?

Comment: @shril Yes, you can. you have to write custom association. please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476521/rails-has-many-custom-activerecord-association

Comment: https://mrbrdo.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/manually-preloading-associations-in-rails-using-custom-scopessql/

Answer (score 0):

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :payback_transaction, class_name: 'Transaction', foreign_key: :parent_transaction_id
  belongs_to :debit_transaction, class_name: 'Transaction', foreign_key: :parent_transaction_id, optional: true
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

You may want `has_many` instead of `has_one` if you want multiple paybacks per debit.

Comment: Can anyone help me with the **ActiveRecord Query** for the above question? The records have single `PaybackTransaction` for every `DebitTransaction`.

Comment: @shril what is wrong with the above? That is an `ActiveRecord` association as requested. `Transaction.find(123).payback_transaction` will result in `Transaction` 125 which appears to be your desired result. Although the belongs to needs a foreign key as well