# Two fields of has many to same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
TransportOrder has many LoadingPlaces as loadings
TransportOrder has many LoadingPlaces as unloadings
```

I can not create two separate models UnloadingPlaces and LoadingPlaces because later I want to search trough LoadingPlaces for TransportOrders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on rails - Reference the same model twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057210/ruby-on-rails-reference-the-same-model-twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use foreign key syntax, and specify the class_name:

```
has_many :loadings, foreign_key: "traport_order_id", class_name: "TransportOrder"
has_many :unloadings, foreign_key: "traport_order_id_two", class_name: "TransportOrder"
```