# SQL relations in Rails. Trying to create two different references for one table relationship. Very confusing situation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, relational-database, db-schema

I have a DB schema where a shipment `belongs_to` two users even though the relation is between model to model.
The shipment can have a `receiver_id` and a `sender_id`. Both the receiver & sender are two different records in the same table (the user model).

I was wondering how can I establish a relationship in my rails backend for a shipment to belong_to a record where the user is the sender as well as another record in the **same DB** where the user is the receiver.
I'v been thinking for ages how to do it, and its very hard to come up with a solution. The only solution I have is to destroy the existing User model, and create two different models: a receiver & a sender. Or is there another solution for this? I've attached my DB schema in this thread.

Any help would much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K26GV.png)

Comment: Check this post: [Ruby on rails - Reference the same model twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2057243/9541423). I think it can help you with your issue.

Comment: thank you very much @sovalina :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Shipment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sent_shipments, :class_name => "Shipment", foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_shipments, :class_name => "Shipment", foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
end
```